# What's the difference between these PHP variables?

Tags: php, oop, variables, properties

I have the following class:

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
    private $connection;
    public $last_query;
    private $magic_quotes_active;
    private $real_escape_string_exits;

public function __construct()...

// 1. OPENS connection and selects a DB
public function open_connection()...

// 2. PERFORMS a DB query
public function query($sql)
{
    $this->last_query = $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    $this->confirm_query($result);
    return $result;
}

....
```

**NOTE:** I included a few lines that are extraneous to my question just to lend some context, they are denoted by `...`

Focusing on `public function query($sql)`, I'm confused by what I see.

1. the `$sql` variable in the method is not defined anywhere other than here, and I believe it's a parameter variable, as in my IDE it's colored slightly differently from other variables. What does that mean and why is it different?
2. `$this->last_query` is also a variable, but needs to be defined within the class, as seen at the top of the class itself. Why does this one need to be defined as such, while the `$sql` variable did not?
3. And finally, `$result` appears to be a standard variable, not a "parameter variable" -- I hope I'm using the right language. Why is this one not defined also? Why is it used like this within this class?

I'm really hoping to understand the differences between these guys so I can get a better handle on using them.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private $connection;
public $last_query;
private $magic_quotes_active;
private $real_escape_string_exits;
```

Above variables are member variables of your class. They are available inside any function of your class and they can be accessed with `$this->`.

`$sql` is the parameter of your `query` function meaning that its scope is only inside this function and can not be accessed from within any other function. The same applies for the local variable `$result`. It is also only available inside the `query` function.

Answer (score 1):

`$sql` is a parameter variable. Whenever you want to execute the code that is in that function, you have to specify what `$sql` should be by passing it as an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

`$result` becomes defined when you assign something to it. In PHP, you do not need to declare variables to use them, but you do need to declare class fields.

I recommend you read some PHP tutorials before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

`$sql` is an argument for `query` function. It does not need to declare to work in whole of your class block by default. Don't forget that you can not access to point it as a class property in your project.

But, `$last_query` defined as a property for your class. You can access to it everywhere in your class and for this reason you must point to it like `$this->last_query`;

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/ is a good simple tutorial for OOP in PHP. Take a look at it ...

Answer (score 1):

Look. PHP, like javascript, is a loosely typed language. The variable's type can dynamically change. So we need not explicitly declare the type of variable (int / String/ char / byte).

$sql is passed as a parameter. PHP doesnt cares about it's type.